# lists vs sets in python recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I ran the following python code:

```
def pr1(li):
    if len(li) == 1:
        print(li)
    else: 
        li[0] += 1
        pr1(li[0:-1])
        print(li)

def pr2(li, n=1):
    if len(li) == 1:
        print(li)
    else: 
        li.remove(n)
        pr2(li, n+1)
        print(li)

pr1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
pr2({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```

and I got the output:

```
[5]
[5, 2]
[4, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
{5}
{5}
{5}
{5}
{5}
```

It seems that recursing over lists creates a new instance whereas recursing over sets doesn't, which is weird. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pr1` function passes a copy of the list to the next level of recursion but your `pr2` function passes the modified set down.  This allows the `pr2` function to mess up the content of the set inside the recursion and you end up printing only the last content of the set when coming back from the lower levels.

try calling `pr2(set(li),n+1)` to avoid this interference